# Download subtitles of facebook video

Tags: python, selenium, facebook, automation

I am working on a project for which I need to download subtitles for a bunch of  Facebook videos. I believe some people upload subtitles and some do not, I want to download the subtitles for the videos for which the subtitles are uploaded or generated by Facebook.

More specifically I want to automate this [link here](https://digitalanarchy.com/blog/art-technology/downloading-the-captions-facebook-or-youtube-creates/)

I believe python-selenium automation might be the answer for this. Anyone who might have done this or have some resources, please help. Thank you.

Edit 1: I think I should have added this in the original post, I do not want the entire script but I only want to understand how automate the search for "srt", the XHR file as shown in the link. I know this has something to do with ChromeDev Tool protocol but I am unable to understand how to go about automating the search for "srt" as shown in the link and download the XHR file.

The current approach I am following is to download the video, convert it to audio and use Google Speech recognition API to convert it to text. But the problem is that the free version of API is generating very poor results. I am doing this using python.

Comment: Have you tried to do it yourself with selenium? If you did - where did you get stuck? If you did not - why? ;)

Comment: There are plenty of users here who could probably write a script for you, but normally we get paid to do that :) If you've attempted this and are stuck on something, please share your code, otherwise this question will likely be closed.

Answer (score 0):

- I think it's will be too long script so no one can write it for you for free
- But you should to check [Selenium WebDriver Docs](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/getting_started/)
- Also you can use `Selenium IDE Extention` to find the elements easily
- I was done a script to login to facebook before in `JavaScript` not `Python` i hope this can help you to continue

> Here's the code

```
var {Builder, By, Key, until} = require('selenium-webdriver');
 (async function() {
  var driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('firefox').build();
  try {
   let url = 'https://www.facebook.com/groups/id';
   driver.get(url)
   var arr = [
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form[@id='login_form']/div/div/label/input")), 
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form[@id='login_form']/div/label/input"))
   ];
   var vArr = ["email@example.com", "012345678"];
   for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    await arr[i].sendKeys(vArr[i])
   }
  await driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form[@id='login_form']/div/div[3]/div/div/div/span/span")).click();
   
 } 
 finally {
  driver.quit()
 }
})();
```